# iReport table joining issues and results in repeating values

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, report, reporting

**I want to start by saying I have looked, researched and tried the other questions posted on SO that may relate to this issue I am having. None have worked and none relate to this problem**

I am writing a report that uses data from both a SO (salesorder) table and WO (workorder) table. I display in the photos 2 scenerios. When I run the report with just the Part, Description, SO# and SO quantity the report runs perfect :)!

**The issue is when I add the WO tables and add the values** WO# and Quantity.
I know it must have something to do with either how the tables are being joined **or** how an iReport setting.

**To clarify what is happeneing in the pictures**, with the tables, I am using the **PART** table as the primary key and what the report is supposed to do is show me, based off of the part selected, any parts still "not finished" in the SO and WO. So a SO could still have a part that has not been "picked and packed" and a WO could also have a part that has not been "picked and packed" but you can have a WO and not a SO and vice versa.

**Question**: How do I keep my WO# and WO Qty values from repeating like they are and messing up my sums at the end? Since the values are repeating my sum function keeps adding them up and giving false numbers.
Thank you for any help given!

---

These are the photos. The report works perfect until I add the WO tables and values- this is shown in the photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**NOW the next 4 photos are when I add the WO tables and the results there after**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it seems to me that I help you the other day with a question refereeing evaluation time on variables... where did that one go?, did you delete it after that I had answered it.... If so it has no sense that I write an answer... since I do the effort no just being helpful to you but to the community.... and if you delete questions and answer... well.. we are not being helpful to the community..

Comment: Actually you insisted that I "remove the question" because I had figured it out before you answered it. I will gladly unDelete the question if you believe it will help others but next time you give an answer (which I honestly appreciate!) try not to come across as so pushy and arrogant :/. You've answered on a question or two of mine and refuse to help until you make a rash comment or belittle my question. I am simply asking for help- and I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, for that you read it as " pushy and arrogant", I will try to improve my comments. You should have read my comment better, I was simple stating that if you come up with the answer before someone answer (since on these tags its takes hours for someone to answer), it would be nice if you either answer the question yourself or remove the question, because answering takes time and effort, and having a comment.. "I already solved it", is a bit annoying... you think to yourself... "So why did you not answer it!"

Comment: You are 100% correct and I will make sure to either tag the question with my own answer or accept the ones given more quickly. Thank you for your help though- seriously. I try to ask questions in the most in depth way and as clear as possible and I appreciate whether it be you or anyone else to try and help me learn and solve my problems. I apologize as well and I would love any help related to this current question! @PetterFriberg

Comment: Hmmm @PetterFriberg how would I write the group by statement? Maybe group by Part? Or by SO and Wo? Thanks!

Comment: Since this question is complex (also understanding what your data is, relations ecc), to improve your chance of gaining an answer, I suggest you to improve you question like this: 1) Instead of screenshot of query included query as text. 2) Comment as much as you can about the 2 different query results. (i see different SO values 45120 is not present anymore, is this a problem??, or is only the TOTAL SO a problem). If only the TOTAL SO is a problem also include the jrxml definition of this variable.

Comment: you group on everything that is repeated... but since you have no relation between SO and WO (other the PART) it is a bit strange to put them on same row (1 SO is not related to 1 WO), seems more like they should be two different tables??

Comment: @PetterFriberg yes they are two seperate tables. Should i maybe use subreports to show them?

Comment: If you like them two be two distinct tables in your report, you can do 2 subreport every one with the relative query, (in main report use a JREmptyDatasource(1) (or a query that returns 1 record), you can also use jr:table component (but its a little bit more complex i would go for subreport since you seem already to be familiar how to use the detail band)..

Comment: Please undelete the question that you delete for me it seems that it can be useful for others (evaluation time on variables), it just came an new question on this...... I will remove all "pushy and arrogant" comments..

Comment: I will undelete them.

Comment: Undelete the ones that have valid answer, delete the ones that does not have an answer or answer them if you do not have the problem anymore..

Comment: As there doesn't appear to be a relationship between the SO and WO it seems like the design of the report isn't quite correct. How about having columns like this instead:

Part 
Description
Order Type
#
Qty

where Order Type would be either Sales Order or Work Order.
In your SQL query you would need to use a union in which one half got all the sales orders and the other half got the work orders

Comment: Also very refreshing to see misunderstandings resolved so cordially! Good stuff guys.

Comment: @jtsnr could you please give me an example of this? Would this work with a Union or would a subreport be best?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a link between SO and WO so it doesn't seem correct to put both on a single row. If you want to see both types of order on the same report then I suggest each row has data for either a SO or a WO. To get both types of order on the same report you could use a union to return results for each type of order separately. You would need to add some sort of 'type' column to show which type of order is being displayed. Below is a query that could achieve this. I've only included the columns that are critical to the answer. Hopefully you will get the idea. I wasn't sure which was the appropriate column for the qty so this might need changing.

```
SELECT
PART."NUM" AS PART_NUM,
PART."DESCRIPTION" AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
'Sales Order' AS RESULT_TYPE
SO."NUM" ORDER_NUMBER,
SOITEM."QTYTOFULFILL" AS QTY
FROM
"PART" PART
INNER JOIN "PRODUCT" PRODUCT ON PART."ID" = PRODUCT."PARTID" AND PRODUCT."ID" = PART."DEFAULTPRODUCTID"
INNER JOIN "SOITEM" SOITEM ON SOITEM."PRODUCTID" = PRODUCT."ID"
INNER JOIN "SO" SO ON SOITEM."SOID" = SO."ID"
WHERE
PART."NUM" = $P{partNUM}
UNION ALL
SELECT
PART."NUM" AS PART_NUM,
PART."DESCRIPTION" AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
'Work Order' AS RESULT_TYPE,
WO."NUM" AS ORDER_NUMBER,
WOITEM."QTYUSED" AS QTY
FROM
"PART" PART
INNER JOIN "PRODUCT" PRODUCT ON PART."ID" = PRODUCT."PARTID" AND PRODUCT."ID" = PART."DEFAULTPRODUCTID"
INNER JOIN "WOITEM" WOITEM ON PART."ID" = WOITEM."PARTID"
INNER JOIN "WO" WO ON WOITEM."WOID" = WO."ID"
WHERE
PART."NUM" = $P{partNUM}
```